# Setting state to be the value of the label of a radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, radio-button

I have a list of radio buttons that in a form.

```
<h6>Desired breed (if any)</h6>
            <div className="radio container-fluid">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">Goldendoodle</p>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">English Goldendoodle</p>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">Labradoodle</p>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">Poodle</p>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">Other</p>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  className="checkbox"
                  name="Breed"
                  onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <p className="checkbox">No preference</p>
              </label>
             
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
```

What I am trying to do is have the `Breed` variable set to the value of whatever checkbox is selected. The problem is I am getting `on` for the value instead of what the label says.

I cannot change the radio button's name attribute because I need only one to be selectable at a time. (I am open to other ways to accomplish this too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change `onClick` like so:

```
onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.nextSibling.textContent)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="radio" />` elements don't have any value, that is the reason why `"on"` is used. When providing a `value` property to each `<input />` you can see that the state correctly updates.

This also allows you to separate the actual value from the label displayed. For example say that your interface is available in multiple languages. In such a scenario you would use different labels for each language, but the values would stay the same.

```js
function App() {
  const [breed, setBreed] = React.useState(null);
  
  console.log(breed);

  return (
    <div>
      <h6>Desired breed (if any)</h6>
      <div className="radio container-fluid">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="Goldendoodle"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">Goldendoodle</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="English Goldendoodle"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">English Goldendoodle</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="Labradoodle"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">Labradoodle</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="Poodle"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">Poodle</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="Other"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">Other</p>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            className="checkbox"
            name="Breed"
            value="No preference"
            onClick={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="checkbox">No preference</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```